# Replace variable values whenever input is issued

Tags: java, overwrite

I want to write a code that counts minutes in last three days. Let's say user makes an input every new day. He can see the sum of minutes for the last three days.

I need to replace variables values whenever the new input is issued. 
So when the first input is created it goes to variable c. 
When the new input is created its value goes to variable c, the value of former variable c goes to b. 
When the next input is created the new value goes to c, the former c goes to b and the former b goes to a and so on

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass2{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        double a=0, b=0, c=0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Input some minutes: ");
        c = input.nextDouble();

        //b=c, a=b;
```

Comment: You might want to use an array or list, instead of multiple variables

Comment: Thank you! 
I asked this question just because couldn't find it on search.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class NewClass2{
     public static void main (String[] args){

        double a=0, b=0, c=0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Input some minutes: ");
        a=b;
        b=c;
        c = input.nextDouble();


      }
```